# Bluetooth broken - not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

In the "Bluetooth" application, I can't enable Bluetooth. It is disabled and I can't move the switch.

I've added `rfkill unblock bluetooth` to `/etc/rc.local` and restarted the computer.

I've checked `rfkill list` and bluetooth isn't showing up.

Running `lsmod  | grep blue` shows:

```
bluetooth             520192  5 bnep
```

not sure what this means.

Running `bluetoothd` shows this:

```
D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.171" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 - running `hwinfo` shows this:

```
  bluetooth 520192 5 bnep, Live 0x0000000000000000
```

Furthermore I dont' see any bluetooth indicator in the status bar.

In response to comment:

```
> lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [103c:172a]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
43:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:4239] (rev 35)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN [8086:1311]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0fca:8031 Research In Motion, Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0007 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS451 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Have the same problem, I haven't been able to find answers so far